# How to understand the `org = super(Singleton, cls)` and `org.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)`?

Tags: python

How to understand this code:

I am researching the Singleton of Python implementation:

```
class Singleton(object):
    ''''' A python style singleton '''

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if not hasattr(cls, '_instance'):
            org = super(Singleton, cls)  # what does this line mean, what's the funciton of it?  
            cls._instance = org.__new__(cls, *args, **kw) # and this line
        return cls._instance


if __name__ == '__main__':
    class SingleSpam(Singleton):
        def __init__(self, s):
            self.s = s

        def __str__(self):
            return self.s


    s1 = SingleSpam('spam')
    print id(s1), s1
    s2 = SingleSpam('spa')
    print id(s2), s2
    print id(s1), s1
```

I do not understand the two lines code:

```
org = super(Singleton, cls)  
cls._instance = org.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
```

1. whether the `cls` equals `self`?
2. what's the meaning of `org = super(Singleton, cls)`?
3. why use `org.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)` for creating the Singleton instance's property `_instance`?

Comment: `__new__` gets passed the *class* as the first parameter, note, it can't be the instance, because before `__new__`, the instance *doesn't exist*. `__new__` is the *constructor*. All these lines are doing is using the super-classes constructor if the instance doesn't exist, and if it does, simply return that instance

Comment: As a side note: There's rarely a good use for `Singleton` in Python. This is mainly useful as a demonstration of `__new__`, `super`, and all the related features. Which is great, since that seems to be what you're using it for. But, while it was a great example for Python 2.1 experts who needed to know the new features in 2.2; I'm not sure it's as helpful for people starting with 2.7 or 3.7. It might be more helpful to learn about descriptors first (starting with normal methods, `@property`, and `@classmethod`), after which `super` and `__new__` are a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whether the `cls` equals `self`?

No, [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) is a static method (automatically, without needing the `@staticmethod` decorator) that doesn't take a `self`. Which is good, because there is no `self` to pass it—the whole point of `__new__` is to *create* that `self` and return it.<sup>1</sup>

So, its first argument, `cls`, is the type of object Python wants it to create. Here, that will be `Singleton`.

In particular, when you write this:

```
obj = Singleton()
```

… what Python turns that into is something like this (slightly oversimplified):

```
obj = Singleton.__new__(Singleton)
if isinstance(obj, Singleton):
    obj.__init__()
```

---

> what's the meaning of `org = super(Singleton, cls)`?

What [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) does is:

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that used by `getattr()` except that the type itself is skipped.

In other words, `super(Singleton, cls)` is an object that acts just like `cls`—which, remember, is `Singleton`—except that when you try to call methods on it, it skips methods defined in `Singleton` and only finds methods defined in the next class in method resolution order—in this case, that's `object`.

---

> why use `org.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)` for creating the Singleton instance's property `_instance`?

Remember that `cls` is `Singleton`, and `org` is a super proxy object, that references the same class object as `cls`, but has the methods of `object` instead of the methods of `Singleton`.<sup>2</sup>

So, when you call `org.__new__`, instead of calling the `Singleton.__new__` code again and getting stuck in an infinite loop, it calls the `object.__new__` code. But we pass it `cls`—that is, `Singleton`—as its argument. So, we're asking the `object` type to create a new object of type `Singleton`. The result, then, is a `Singleton` instance, which we `return`.

But first, we store it `cls._instance`—that is, `Singleton._instance`—so the next time we try to create a `Singleton`, we can just return the same `cls._instance`.

---

If we just wanted a single `Singleton` class that didn't do anything, it could be a little bit simpler. But `Singleton` can be subclassed, and each of its subclasses will be a singleton class. Start with this:

```
class SingleSub(Singleton):
    pass

obj = SingleSub()
```

So this is going to call `SingleSub.__new__(SingleSub)`. Since `SingleSub` doesn't override `__new__`, that calls `Singleton.__new__(SingleSub)`, so, inside that code, `cls` is now `SingleSub` instead of `Singleton`.

And you should be able to trace things through from there and see how `SingleSub` ends up with a single `_instance`, distinct from any other subclass of `Singleton` (and its `__init__` gets called exactly when you'd expect, and so on).

---

<sub>1. Of course, unless you're writing an extension module (e.g., a C module for CPython), you have no way of creating a `self`. That's why you delegate it to your `super`—ultimately it gets to `object`, or some other builtin/extension type, which *does* know how to create an instance. And of course you can modify the arguments passed up the chain, or the `self` passed down the chain.</sub>

<sub>2. Under the covers, this works much the same way methods themselves work, which should make things a lot clearer if you already know how methods work, but if you don't it'll probably be more confusing than enlightening, so don't worry about it. But at some point, you should work through the [Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). It's tough going, but once you get that idea, all of the "magic" in Python becomes clear.</sub>